# How to use Gradle daemon in a Kubernetes CI pipeline?

Tags: gradle, kubernetes, continuous-integration

I'm using [Jenkins with Kubernetes plugin](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/jenkins) but I think the problem will be the same with Tekton or any pipeline that build, test, and deploy a project using Kubernetes'pods and Gradle.

Is there a way to share the Gradle daemon process through multiple pods?

Note that I enabled remote Gradle caches.

Answer (score 2):

Not easily. The whole model of the Kubernetes plugin is that every build runs in a new environment. You would have to run it outside of the build, probably via a DaemonSet with hostNetwork mode on and then configure Gradle in the build to look at a different IP (the host IP) instead of localhost.

Basically everyone just copes with `--no-daemon` mode :-/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I like the idea of the DaemonSet. Would you have any kind of suggestion to configure Gradle to look at a different IP ? Do I have to patch it ? Note: I remove `--no-daemon` according to this discussion : https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2824

Comment: No idea on the IP config. I did a quick look and I can’t find the code for how it actually talks to the daemon.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, you have gradle caching enabled. And when you are running parallel Jenkins build pipelines it is failing as the first gradle daemon process would have created the lock on the files. 
If that's the case, as a work around you can define host path volume in your Kubernetes pod template, specifically for your each gradle build job and while doing gradle build, pass that particular path for gradle caching.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's out of scope. I have no build problem. Just performance reflexion :)